# isDigit() for rational numbers?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to evaluate if the string in one of the textbox of my interface is a number (i.e. not text or anything else). In Python, there is a method called isdigit() that will return True if the string only contains digits (no negative signs or decimal points). Is there another way I could evaluate if my string is a rational number (ex: 1.25).

Example code:

```
if self.components.txtZoomPos.text.isdigit():
        step = int(self.components.txtZoomPos.text)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.25 is a notation commonly used for [reals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number), less so for [rational numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number). Python's [float](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float) will raise a [ValueError](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) when conversion fails. Thus:

```
def isReal(txt):
    try:
        float(txt)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: No, it's both, if you go by the standard maths names. The real number line consists of the rational numbers and irrational numbers, the rational number line is the integers and numbers that can be represented in the form 'a/b' where a and b are integers.

Comment: @workmad3: you're right, which is why I quickly updated my answer (but unfortunately after you saw it ;) )

Comment: +1, I was just typing up the same thing when your answer appeared.  Darn!  Missed the rep points!

Answer (score 1):

`try`/`catch` is very cheap in Python, and attempting to construct a `float` from a string that's not a number raises an exception:

```
>>> float('1.45')
1.45
>>> float('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): foo
```

You can just do something like:

```
try:
    # validate it's a float
    value = float(self.components.txtZoomPos.text)
except ValueError, ve:
    pass # your error handling goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are correct in that the more Pythonic way is usually to `try...except` (i.e. EAFP).

However, if you really want to do the validation, you could remove exactly 1 decimal point before using `isdigit()`.

```
>>> "124".replace(".", "", 1).isdigit()
True
>>> "12.4".replace(".", "", 1).isdigit()
True
>>> "12..4".replace(".", "", 1).isdigit()
False
>>> "192.168.1.1".replace(".", "", 1).isdigit()
False
```

Notice that this does not treat floats any different from ints however. You could add that check if you really need it though.

Answer (score 0):

int() or float() throws ValueError if the literal is not valid

Answer (score 0):

`float()` throws a `ValueError` if the conversion fails.  So try to convert your string to a float, and catch the `ValueError`.